# How to route to specific docker container based on user request

Tags: api, docker

I'm trying to create a service that:

1. only one outgoing port
2. all containers connect to that port
3. route a request to specific docker container based on the user request info
   (I want to provide 1 container to serve each user)

Is there any possible solution for this?
Any suggestion would be appreciated.

Thanks!

Comment: the scenario is that:
when I got a request, I update the config file & start a container to service specific user

Comment: You can do this, but running a container for each user can be both tricky and wasteful.  You’d need to build a proxy of some sort that identified the user, discovered the appropriate backend pod, and forwarded the request.  Do you have an existing implementation you need help with?

Comment: Also note that you can’t start a container without potentially having unrestricted root-level access to the host (if you can start a container then you can run it as root and bind-mount the host’s root filesystem), which you generally don’t want to do from a network-facing container.  This doesn’t strike me as a great design choice.

Comment: @DavidMaze so what you mean is that I should provide only one container with account management feature(access control) for all users? Then auto-scale up if needed, right?